# how do I test a basic javascript file with mocha?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js

I'm missing something obvious here with Mocha and Coffeescript/Javascript.

I've got a file in `/static/js/` called `ss.coffee`, it's very simple, just one function:

```
function sortRowCol(a, b) {
    if (a.r == b.r)
        if (a.c == b.c)
            return 0;
        else if (a.c > b.c)
            return 1;
        else return -1;
    else if (a.r > b.r)
        return 1;
    else return -1;
}
```

The function works correctly, but I decided I needed to start testing this project today, so I put in a mocha test file:

```
require "../static/js/ss.coffee"

chai = require 'chai'
chai.should()

describe 'SS', ->
    describe '#sortRowCol(a,b)', ->
      it 'should have a sorting function', ->
        f = sortRowCol
        debugger
        console.log 'checking sort row'
        f.should.not.equal(null, "didn't find the sortRowCol function")
    describe 'sortRowCol(a, b)', ->
      it 'should return -1 when first row is less than second', ->
        a = {r: 2, c: "A"}
        b = {r: 1, c: "A"}
        r = sortRowCol a, b
        r.should.equal(-1, "didn't get the correct value")
```

Something isn't right, because my results are:

```
 $  mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script ./test/ss.coffee -R spec           
 SS                                                                      
   #sortRowCol(a,b)                                                              
     1) should have a sorting function                                           
   sortRowCol(a, b)                                                              
     2) should return -1 when first row is less than second                      


 × 2 of 2 tests failed:                                                          

 1) SS #sortRowCol(a,b) should have a sorting function:                 
    ReferenceError: sortRowCol is not defined
```

It's finding the file correctly, because it will error with 'Cannot find module' if I change that to a non-existent file name.

I tried changing `sortRowCol(a,b)` to `#sortRowCol(a, b)` and vice versa, didn't help. The docs ([link](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/)) don't really explain what that # is doing there, is that just a ruby idiom that's here for some reason?

There must be something wrong with how I'm referencing the ss.coffee file, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By `require`ing the script in Node, it'll be treated as any other [module](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), isolating `sortRowCol` as a local within a closure. The script will have to use `exports` or `module.exports` to make it available to `mocha`:

```
function sortRowCol(a, b) {
    // ...
}

if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports != null) {
    exports.sortRowCol = sortRowCol;
}
```

```
ss = require "../static/js/ss.coffee"
sortRowCol = ss.sortRowCol

# ...
```

As for...

> The docs (link) don't really explain what that # is doing there, [...]

AFAIK, a `#` is typically used to imply that it's a method -- e.g., `Constructor#methodName`. Not really sure if that applies here, though.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204021/how-do-i-test-normal-non-node-specific-javascript-functions-with-mocha while you were writing this answer. I assumed that about the # but it seems very Ruby-ish, doesn't it? Seems a bit out of place.