# Testing client-side js with mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm trying to test my .js class (not a node one) with mocha. I face a problem as I don't know how to import it as it's not wrapped with module.exports or anything else. So, my .js is like

```
var User = function() {
  this.add = function() { ... }
  this.update = function() { ... }
}
```

And I want to test one of its functions in test

```
var User = require('path/to/user.js');

describe('User object', function () {
  it('should add some stuff', function () {
    var user = new User();
    ...
  })
});
```

This (with and without "var User =") predictably gives me "undefined is not a function". What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I test 'normal' (non-Node specific) JavaScript functions with Mocha?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204021/how-do-i-test-normal-non-node-specific-javascript-functions-with-mocha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @mfreitas I've found solution. Regarding my problem, it's just needed to add to the end of **user.js**

```
if(typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
  exports.User = User;
}
```

and update mocha test

```
var user = new User.User();
```

Looks not so awesome as it could, but still works ;) Hope it will help someone.